# How can I clone Test Cases between Test Plans?

Tags: testing, azure-devops

I need to clone certain Test Suites from one test plan to another.

A test plan is made up of test suites and those test suites are made up of test cases.

So I would like to take a test Suite Id and clone/copy it over to a new test plan.

We are using Azure Dev Ops online.

Is this possible or am I looking at it via the wrong way?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65830322/9688376

Answer (score 2):

This was something I noticed when upgrading from using MTM for test case management.  It seems like this kind of option was missing.  I made a [developer community post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/394111/clone-test-plan.html) asking for clarity on whether this was a gap.

Current Response:

> Thank you for your feedback!
>
> According to your description , I suggest you install [Test Case Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer) extension and then you can access to Test Case -> Pivot by Test plan -> click “Clone test plan”, set Area path and Iteration path, then Clone.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you Matt. I can do that and have installed the extension. I want to be able to put a specific suite in a test plan though and I think you have to add via Test Cases and not Test Suites. I'm just trying to make sure I'm reading into that right.

Comment: Matt, I added my scenario to the developer community post.

Comment: @tvb108108, you might want to open a new issue with them.  I don't know how frequently they review already closed issues.