# How to copy test plan from one team project to another in azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have this test plan with all these test suits in one project, I now want it in another project. Both the projects are in the same devops account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clone Test Cases between Test Plans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313213/how-can-i-clone-test-cases-between-test-plans)

Comment: @Matt it is not a duplicate, cloning test plans between projects is *extremely* different from cloning tests between plans.

Comment: @pxtl You can say that, but if you look at the answer from the linked question and what the submitter provided as "their solution" to their question they are identical.  The extension is giving you the option to cloning a Test Plan to a different project.  I'm more than 4 years removed having to do anything with ADO tests though, so probably don't have the context anymore to provide useful further input.

Answer (score 2):

- Right-click on the suite
- Import test suites
- Select from suite

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just tried this and while at first I was really impressed, the problem is that the tests are copied by-ref and not including the area path.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the solution.

1. I had to install the following plugin,
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer
2. (In the source project) Then back in TFS under "Test Plans" select "Test Cases".
3. Set "Pivot By" to "Test Plan" and choose your test plan from the drop down next to "Test Plan".
4. Then Click on the clone icon.
   [image]
5. Then in the dialogue box set the project name to the destination project name and hit Clone.

Answer (score -2):

Would the azure cli copy command help? Take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-azure-cli